# How to use auto_route and modal_bottom_sheet with deep linking in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, router

I get an error that the navigator's overlay is null. I don't understand what I can do about it.
My deep link looks like:

```bash
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "https://my.app.com/news/xx-xx-xx" \
    com.app.my
```

My router code heavily inspired by https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/675:

```dart
...
AutoRoute(
        path: 'news',
        page: EmptyRouterPage,
        name: 'NewsTab',
        children: [
          AutoRoute(
            page: NewsCategoryScreen,
            name: 'NewsCategoryRoute',
            path: 'category/:id',
          ),
          CustomRoute(
            path: ':newsSlug',
            page: NewsDetailScreen,
            name: 'NewsDetailOverlay',
            fullscreenDialog: false,
            barrierDismissible: true,
            customRouteBuilder: modalSheetBuilder,
            maintainState: true,
            usesPathAsKey: true,
          ),
          AutoRoute(
            page: NewsListScreen,
            path: '',
            name: 'NewsList',
          ),
          RedirectRoute(path: '', redirectTo: '/')
        ],
      ),
...
Route<T> modalSheetBuilder<T>(
    BuildContext context, Widget child, CustomPage<T> page) {

  return ModalBottomSheetRoute(
    settings: page,
    builder: (context) => child,
    expanded: false,
  );
}
```

My error is:

```
#1      TransitionRoute.install
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:224
#2      ModalRoute.install
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:1180
#3      _RouteEntry.handleAdd
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2822
#4      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:3843
#5      NavigatorState.restoreState
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:3324
#6      RestorationMixin._doRestore
package:flutter/…/widgets/restoration.dart:872
#7      RestorationMixin.didChangeDependencies
package:flutter/…/widgets/restoration.dart:858
#8      NavigatorState.didChangeDependencies
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:3342
#9      StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5036
#10     ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4853
#11     Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3863
#12     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3586
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4904
#14     StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5050
#15     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#16     StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5082
#17     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3570
#18     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4904
#19     StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5050
#20     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#21     StatefulElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5082
#22     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3570
#23     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4904
#24     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#25     ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5228
#26     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3570
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4904
#28     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#29     ProxyElement.update
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5228
#30     Element.updateChild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3570
#31     ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4904
#32     StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5050
#33     Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4604
#34     BuildOwner.buildScope
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2667
#35     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:882
#36     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:378
#37     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1175
#38     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1104
#39     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1015
```

The debugger lands on:

```dart
@override
  AnimationController createAnimationController() {
    assert(_animationController == null);
    _animationController = ModalBottomSheet.createAnimationController(
      navigator!.overlay!,
      duration: transitionDuration,
    );
    return _animationController!;
  }
```

in `/Users/$USER/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart` with the overlay being null.

When I navigate to the `NewsListScreen` the deep link works fine.
Other links line `https://my.app.com/news` are working fine too.

How may I prepare the faulty navigator to have a overlay for the animation?

Im using:

- auto_route: ^5.0.2
- modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2

I tried debugging with a Navigation Observer like shown in the auto_route documentation with no obvious solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced same issue by adding Redirect rout it's fixed

here is my route class

```
AutoRoute(
          page: HomeTabRoute.page,
          path: '/home',
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              page: HomeRoute.page,
              path: HomeScreen.routeName,
            ),
            RedirectRoute(
              path: 'art',
              redirectTo: 'art/:id',
            ),
            AutoRoute(
              page: ArtDetailsRoute.page,
              path: 'art/:id',
              maintainState: false,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

On main.dart have to config whole route

```
routerConfig:
      ref.read(appRouterProvider).config(deepLinkBuilder: (deepLink) {
    if (deepLink.path.startsWith('/home')) {
      return DeepLink(
        [
          HomeTabRoute(
            children: [
              ArtDetailsRoute(id: 1),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return DeepLink.defaultPath;
    }
  })
```

here is my deeplink url:

> [http://com.myapp/home/art/1"](http://com.myapp/home/art/1%22)

also add @PathParam('id') on art Detail screen's constructore