# Navigate to needed route using auto_route from notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, deep-linking, auto-route

I have implemented a flutter notification and navigation using auto_route.
I have a case that from notification I get a payload (route path) to navigate to screen.

Question is how to implement the navigation? Is it possible to use deepLinkBuilder of auto_route? if yes, how deepLinkBuilder can be fired from onSelectedNotification method?

Comment: is [how-to-use-auto-route-and-modal-bottom-sheet-with-deep-linking-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221556/how-to-use-auto-route-and-modal-bottom-sheet-with-deep-linking-in-flutter) solves your issue